# Explain the `put` function in the `interactive.mjs` example for Google's zx

Tags: google-zx

I was looking at [this](https://github.com/google/zx/blob/main/examples/interactive.mjs) example from `zx` and I understand that ultimately the script is adding pre-defined values for each prompt from the `npm init` command and then that's getting written to the file system (as usual by `npm init`). What I don't understand, though, is exactly how that is happening with the `put` function in the script.

Can someone please help me understand what exactly is going on here? Thank you!

Replacing `process.stdout.write(text)` seems to have the same effect as `console.log(text)` which is interesting. I've tried various modifications to help understand but it's still eluding me a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Essential part is

```
stdin.write(text)
```

This is enough, but it will not show what we “typed” in our script.

So second line in put just for echoing. console.log will also work.